# How to split text document into variables in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

So I was wondering if there is a way to make a batch file read a separate text document and convert specific lines of code into a variable with the same value given, as from the document. So make the batch script read the text document, and use the information in there to create it's own variable.
eg.

TEXT.txt:

```
test==a
test2==b
test3==c
```

and then the batch script would read that text and convert it into usable variables with the same values as given from the TEXT.txt document

Like so:
Usable batch variable:

```
%test% is "a"
%test2% is "b"
%test3% is "c"
```

and so on

And also, would it be possible for the batch file to read a user input using `set /p opt= Userinput:` and then take user input and convert every letter typed into a seperate individual variable?

eg.
User types in: "hello" when prompted with `set /p opt= Userinput:` and batch script converts user input into:

```
%letter1% is "h" 
%letter2% is "e" 
%letter3% is "l"
%letter4% is "l"
%letter5% is "o"
```

And would it also be possible for the batch script to read spaces in user input like if user input was "hi all" and then the batch script would say

```
%letter1% is "h"
%letter2% is "i" 
%letter3% is "0" 
%letter4% is "a" 
%letter5% is "l" 
%letter6% is "l"
```

Comment: Is each entry on a separate line?  Are you able to get rid of that extra equals symbol?

Comment: @Squashman
Yes, each entry is on a seperate line. Sorry, I couldn't make it display the code correctly for some reason

Comment: Well I fixed it once, so you should have taken a look at how I did it before you overwrote it again. Anyhow, do you want the content of `%test%` to be `==a`, `=a`, or `a`?

Comment: @Compo
I would like for %test% to be "a" in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content as shown in your example `TEXT.txt`, you could just use a `For /F` loop and use the `=` character as the delimiters:

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%G In ('find "=" ^<"TEXT.txt"')Do @Set "%%G=%%H"
```

Although, I'd prefer not to rely upon `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%`:

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="
 0^<"TEXT.txt"') Do @Set "%%G=%%H"
```

---

As for your more interesting question, the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) below attempts to save each character of a users input to separate variables.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:GetInput
Set "Input="
Set /P "Input=Enter your string here>"
If Not Defined Input GoTo GetInput
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Char[) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=0" & For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('(%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /U
 /S /D /C "(Echo=!Input!)"^) ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ""') Do (
    Set /A i += 1 & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!i!) Do EndLocal & Set "Char[%%H]=%%G")

(Set Char[) 2>NUL
Pause
```

The last two lines are added just to give you some visual feedback of what has been done, you would obviously use your own code there…

Comment: So what exactly does it set the variables to be in the first 2 examples? Because I can't seem to figure out what those variables are set as. I've tried `echo %%G`, `echo %%H` and  `echo %Delims%` after running the script on a file containing  the following text `a = hi` Sorry lol, I'm not the best at batch

Comment: It does exactly what your expectation asks @Gabrielnigme20! Given your submitted `TEXT.txt` content, you should be able to print the following anywhere after the provided example code! e.g. `@Echo %%test%% is "%test%"`, `@Echo %%test2%% is "%test2%"`, `@Echo %%test3%% is "%test3%"`. The example you've provided in the comment above however, does not match what your question asked, and therefore the code provided does not provide the results you're expecting. I've answered only the questions you originally asked! That comment will create a variable `%a %` with the content `<space>hi`.

Comment: Oooh, I see. Yeah it works perfectly now that I get it. Sorry for the inconvenience